# Split vs Filter vs Modified Map Function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say you are processing a stream of events that go through two map functions. The first one tries to classify the events according to some criterion, but it might fail in some cases (leaving the event intact). The second one should only act on those events that could not be classified in the first step. I am not sure which strategy would be the best:

1. Split the stream after applying the first operator, apply the second operator only to one of the branches (the one containing the unclassified events) and then join the two streams back again using union
2. Split the stream as in 1 but using filter instead of split
3. Don't split the stream at all after applying the first map operator. Instead, just keep the original stream and modify the second map function to check whether it should act upon the current event or not (based on the first step classification result)

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest approach would be to implement the first map as a ProcessFunction with a [side output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/side_output.html), followed by the second mapper and then a union.

Comment: I am quite new to Flink and I did not even consider this alternative. Learning about side outputs now, thanks!